# while loop is getting the wrong value?

Tags: c++, while-loop

this is my code i did with c++. and the program should only accept numbers. it need four correct input to proceed to next process. and should ignore wrong inputs. the problem is, it accepts 8 correct inputs. it ignores the first 4 correct answer and get the values of the last 4 correct input. it should only ask and get four values. what is wrong with my loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

float a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, grade = 0;


cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 1 : \t";
cin >> a ;          
cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 2 : \t";
cin >> b ;
cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 3 : \t";
cin >> c;
cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 4 : \t";
cin >> d;
```

this is the loop i made so that it will ignore wrong inputs

```
while(!(cin>>a))
    {
        cout<<"Wrong. Try again."<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        system ("cls");
        cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 1 : \t";
        cin >> a ;

         if ( cin>> a){
            break;
        }
        }       

while(!(cin>>b))
    {
        cout<<"Wrong. Try again."<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        system ("cls");
        cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 2 : \t";
        cin >> a ;

         if ( cin>> b){
            break;
        }
        }   

while(!(cin>>c))
    {
        cout<<"Wrong. Try again."<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        system ("cls");
        cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 3 : \t";
        cin >> c ;

         if ( cin>> c){
            break;
        }
        }   

while(!(cin>>d))
    {
        cout<<"Wrong. Try again."<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        system ("cls");
        cout << " Enter your Grade on Quiz no. 4 : \t";
        cin >> a ;

         if ( cin>> d){
            break;
        }
        }
```

it should smoothly proceed here after 4 correct inputs.

```
system ("cls");

cout << "  Quiz#" << "\t\tGrade\n";
cout <<"    1\t\t" << a << endl;
cout <<"    2\t\t" << b << endl;
cout <<"    3\t\t" << c << endl;
cout <<"    4\t\t" << d << endl;
cout << "\n";

cout << " TOTAL AVE."<< "\t\tREMARKS\n";

grade = (a+b+c+d)/ 4;

if (grade> 94 && grade< 101 ) {

    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<<grade << "\t\tExcellent!\n\n";
}

else if (grade> 89 && grade< 95){

    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<< grade << "\t\tVery Satisfactory!\n\n";
}

else if (grade> 84 && grade< 90 ) {

    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<<grade << "\t\tSatisfactory!\n\n";
}

else if (grade> 79 && grade< 85 ) {

    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<<grade << "\t\tFine!\n\n";
}

else if (grade> 74 && grade< 80 ) {

    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<<grade << "\t\t\Fair!\n\n";
}

else if (grade> -1 && grade < 75 ) {

    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<<grade << "\t\t\Poor.\n\n";
}

else { 
    cout << "    " << setw(4)<< left<< "   " << "\t\t\Invalid Input.\n\n";
}

system ("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add more specific tags that will help someone find your question. At least tag the language your code is written in.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of redundant code!

Comment: sorry.. i really have no clue on how to do my assignment..

Comment: Read the code carefully and count how many times you use `>>`. Also check which variables you're reading into.

Comment: While doing that, you should probably also fix things like `cin >> a ;` being embedded in the `while (!(cin >> b))` and `while (!(cin >> d))` loops. They shouldn't be there *at all* much less be reading into `a`. Cut+Paste is no silver bullet.

Comment: @DiamondRaquizaBarrunda There are numerous issues with your code, besides not working. Think about these things: **1** How does one store a number of variables that can be identified by a number in a sequence? **2** Where does one best put a piece of code that should run multiple times with just some minor differences between each call?

Comment: ive been looking at it for hours,, i still cant find it. please tell me

Comment: @DiamondRaquizaBarrunda then you haven't been looking hard enough. Ex: How many times should your code have `cin >> a`, for example? The negation of its result in the first loop condition seems logical. So why does it appear **4** more times in other places? *That* is what molbdnilo was referring to. The redundancy pointed out Biffen is simply a hint to an alternate way of accomplishing the task, but the code you posted has logical errors like I just pointed out *multiple* times.